# Caliburn Micro WPF: Message.Attach with guard property disables whole host control

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro (2.0.2, currently the latest version) with a WPF application. Say I have a simple list of items, and I want to enable some action on the selected item. The action is bound to a button.

So, my VM exposes a bindable collection of those items (e.g. `Persons`), and an object of the same type bound to the selected item (e.g. `SelectedPerson`). Say the action corresponds to a method named `Test`, and I have a guard property `CanTest`, which returns true when the selected item is not null. When `SelectedPerson` changes, I also call `NotifyOfPropertyChanged` for `CanTest`.

This trivial scenario works fine: when nothing is selected the button corresponding to my action is disabled; when I select any item, it gets enabled.

The issue arises when I bind the method to a control event, using `Message.Attach`: say I want to attach it to mouse double click. My XAML would look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons,Mode=OneWay}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson,Mode=TwoWay}"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action Test]"/>
```

This totally disables the control (the whole control, not only the descendant button, so that I can never select an item in the ListBox, which stays disabled forever). The only way I have to enable it is to remove the guard property from my VM (or the `Message.Attach` from the view).

You can find a simple repro at http://1drv.ms/1OTSgq2.

I also found this post at https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/246571, which seems to suggest that attaching a message disables the convention-based logic for guard properties, so that you have to explicitly bind the `IsEnabled` property of the control to your guard property. I tried this, but nothing changes.

Comment: Currently this behavior is as expected, CM disables the attached control if the guard evaluates to false. What's your desired outcome for the guard property? Just to stop the call or to have any UI behavior?

Comment: Thank you. I'd just like to stop the call, as the method acts on a selected item, which is null when no selection exists; it's a nice touch having the button disabled when no selection is in place, and enabling it when an item is selected. Of course I can live without it, and just check for null and return at the beginning of my method.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by having the button disabled here as the message is attached to the ListBox. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean that I have a button acting on the selected item of a listbox, and this being the default action for that list I'd like to invoke it also by double clicking the listbox item. Thus, both the button and the message action refer to the same method in the VM.What I'd want is having the button disabled when no item is selected in the list, but this being right what happens when the view loads (no item is initially selected), both the button and the listbox get disabled. This way I can never select an item.

Comment: Ok, well as the answer says there's no real way around this given the attaching messages and guard properties work. It always disables the control it's attached to.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Anyway I can use the suggested workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Caliburn's conventions, in your case I would suggest to merely change the property name of `CanTest` to something like `IsTestEnabled`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit counter-intuitive as my code will thus mix guard properties named after their methods with guard properties with a different naming but with the same purpose; yet it seems the only viable workaround.